can't copy a file over cifs
I'm experiencing an issue with my SMB / CIFS over NAS QNAP setup:
//qnap.local/folder_x on /media/folder_x type cifs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=2.0,cache=strict,username=admin,uid=1000,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.x.xxx,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,iocharset=utf8,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=1)

Since the last Ubuntu update (22.04 LTS) or QNAP update, I've been unable to copy files from the client. Dolphin freezes, and I can't access the entire folder again, neither through Dolphin nor through the Terminal command 'ls' — it shows only the promt.
In the first step, perhaps I need a log for the failed copy process. Where can I find this?
I tested on 2 Ubuntu-clients (failed both) - Windows-clients works.
best

This sounds like it might be caused by this kernel bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/2061026
Rebooting into an older kernel version through the GRUB menu worked for me (I used 6.1.0), or upgrading the kernel version to 6.5.0-35 as mentioned in that ticket should also do the trick.

Sounds like my problem... your right. I solved the Problem by installing Ubuntu again.
I figured it out because I have a third Ubuntu client that runs smoothly and has only one difference: I had directly installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it. In contrast to the other two, which had received Ubuntu 22.04 through upgrades.
